# Software needed to compile and execute J2ME programs

Tags: java, java-me

I want to know the required software which is needed for J2ME programs
I am having the JDK 1.6.0
I do not want to use an IDE at this moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to go with the IDE then you only need mobile sdk from oracle for compiling your midlets avaliable here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/javamobile/download/overview/index.html

I would strongly encourage you to switch into IDE like Netbeans for J2ME as it would get much easier for you to run/test and deploy your mobile applications

Comment: You said no IDE than you need only SDK, but if i go with IDE than is there anything else that i need?

Comment: Download netbeans http://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html containing the Java ME bundle, you would have to probably download the ME SDK separately and set it in netbeans but not sure as I haven't used for a long time.

Answer (score 7):

Now you need to install the [J2ME Wireless Toolkit](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/download-135801.html),

Have a look at this tutorial : [J2ME Tutorial](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2005/02/09/j2me1.html)

Comment: Thanks sanjay.......The link says J2ME wireless toolkit is now integrated with Java ME SDK. SO will there be difference in compiling and executing using toolkit and SDK?

Answer (score 1):

[J2SDK1.6.0](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/index.html)

[Eclipse 3.7](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/index.php): one of the best Java IDE ;-)

[J2ME Wireless toolkit 2.5](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-137162.html)

[EclipseME 1.7](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipseme/files/): Eclipse plugin to help develop J2ME code

[ProGuard 4.7](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/):  class file shrinker and obfuscator.

Comment: The question explicitly stated that they would not like to use an IDE